# Node Express forwarding html

Tags: node.js, express, parsing

I was woundering how to forward user selected html (radios and checkboxes) that is posted by a user **as is** to a newly rendered website using nodejs

That means user selected radio buttons and checkboxes, as well as unselected buttons and radios would be as per user selection and with the html tags

Comment: Can you be more clear/detailed on your question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [Express](https://expressjs.com) with [Pug](https://pugjs.org), here's an example.

```
form
    input(type="checkbox" value="checked" name="checkbox" checked)
    input(type="radio" value="checked" name="radio" checked)
    input(type="submit", value="Submit")
```

When this form submits, the express handler will receive the form data, an example handler:

```js
    router.use(bodyParser().urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    router.post('/form',(req,res) => {
        //req.body: { checkbox: 'checked', radio: 'checked' }
        res.render('anotherPage', {radio: req.body.radio, checkbox: req.body.checkbox});
    })
```

Then in `anotherPage.pug`

```
form
    input(type="checkbox" value="checked" name="checkbox" checked=checkbox)
    input(type="radio" value="checked" name="radio" checked=radio)
    input(type="submit", value="Submit")
```

This way, the data can be passed on to the anotherPage.pug while maintaining the fields from the original page. You can also do this with other input types, such as text, by simply taking their value and passing it to the pug renderer.